# Make an array listing custom taxonomy

Tags: php, categories

I am trying to populate an array with a list of categories in a custom taxonomy I created.

The taxonomy, called *clips*, has a slug called *clipcat*. I only want the array to populate with children of a clip with the same slug as the page slug the list is on.

Here's my code so far:

```
   <?php 
        global $post;
        $slug = get_post( $post )->post_name;
        $taxes = array('clipcat');
        $args = array(
            'parent' => $slug,
        ); 
        $categories = get_terms( $taxes, $args );
        print_r($categories);
   ?>
```

To my knowledge, the code is as it should be, but when I print the array (the last line in the code), the array is empty even though I know the clip category that is successfully assigned to `$slug` has three sub categories (so I must be coding something wrong).

Any suggestions to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The parent arg accepts an integer(ID), you are passing the slug.

Comment: Also, make sure you want `'parent'` and not '`child_of'`.